# Do Hybris Charon web-service method implementations (with Observable return type) run asynchronously out of the box?

Tags: rx-java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have some Hybris Charon (rxJava based implementation) based services configured (with Observable return types) in my project. Couple of those services are being invoked from single methods call. When I checked logs, found them running parallel. However when I created a sample POC using rxJava and created multiple observables, I found them running synchronously (one after another, unless explicitly configured to run on new thread). That's why my question is, whether Charon is configured to async (when using Observable return types) out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Charon is using RxJava version 1.x, which is no longer maintained. The latest version of RxJava is 2.x. I'm also not use if Charon is still maintained. Nevertheless, you should be able to call RxJava1.x Observables ansynchronously out of the box with this project. If you would like to use RxJava 2.x, probably you'll need to use interop libraries to convert RxJava 1.x types to 2.x.

Comment: Yes Charon with my version of Hybris(6.6 ) is using rxJava 1.1.6. And I used the same rxJava version for my POC. I just want to be sure that Charon is invoking method calls async, else I would need to configure my code explicitly to run async. Even better if I could get Charon code pointers to prove the case.

Comment: I don't know that. I think, Observable is just an API, which allows you to write async  code quite easily and you can handle that by yourself. Nevertheless, I don't know if Charon handles its operations asynchronously under the hood or not and just exposes Observables in its API.